# Delete file on applicationSupportDirectory - Swift 5

Tags: swift

How can I delete a single file from `applicationSupportDirectory`? This is what I'm using to create it:

```
func encodeFileStoredInDisk<U : Encodable>(dataToStore: U, fileName: String, fileExtension: String) throws {
    let fileURL = try FileManager.default
        .url(for: .applicationSupportDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: true)
        .appendingPathComponent(fileName)
        .appendingPathExtension(fileExtension)

    try JSONEncoder().encode(dataToStore)
        .write(to: fileURL)
}
```

I tried this based on the docs but it's unrecognizable, which hints me it's completly wrong:

```
func deleteFileOnDisk(fileName: String, fileExtension: String) throws {
    let fileURL = try FileManager.default
        .url(for: .applicationSupportDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: false)
        .appendingPathComponent(fileName)
        .appendingPathExtension(fileExtension)
    
    removeItem(at URL: fileURL)
}
```

Comment: Use [FileManager](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/filemanager/1413590-removeitem)

Comment: I went over that documentation but don't understand it, Apple is finally doing some effort on the docs. but that one is not updated yet. That looks to me like a func declaration only. I edited my response, with what've tried @vadian

Comment: `try FileManager.default.removeItem(at: fileURL)`. Any method marked as `throws` must be called with `try`

Comment: it says: `Cannot find 'removeItem' in scope` Do I have to import something? @vadian

Comment: Please see the edit

Comment: Perfect, that worked, Thanks!@vadian do you want to post the answer or do I post it? I couldn't find this question before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your given code already reveals how to call a method which belongs to `FileManager` so start with

```
FileManager.default.rem
```

Code completion will suggest

```
FileManager.default.removeItem(at: <#T##URL#>)
```

and will tell you also to mark the method with `try`, click on the red circle in front of the error message and choose the first `Fix` option

```
try FileManager.default.removeItem(at: fileURL)
```